# Testing react component when state changes

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

This is my code. I want to test the text in the component once the state is updated. But In the console It's showing loading component.

I'm using Jest and Enzyme.

This is App.js code

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [isDataLoaded, setIsDataLoaded] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDataLoaded) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [isDataLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setIsDataLoaded(true), 4000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading && <div>Loading....</div>}
      {!isLoading && (
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is App.test.js code

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App";

let wrapper;

const setup = (state = {}) => {
  const mockUseState = jest.fn().mockReturnValue([{ ...state }, jest.fn()]);
  React.useState = mockUseState;
  return mount(<App />);
};

// beforeEach(() => {
//   wrapper = setup();
// });

// afterEach(() => {
//   wrapper.unmount();
// });

describe("App", () => {
  test("renders without error", () => {
    wrapper = setup();
    expect(wrapper.find("App").exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  test("renders learn react link", () => {
    wrapper = setup({ isLoading: false });
    wrapper.setProps();
    console.log(wrapper.debug(), "console output")
    expect(wrapper.find("App-link").text()).toBe("Learn React");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mocked `React.useState` which will breaks the real function of `useState`.   Keep using the real `React.useState` and use faker timers to mock the timer for `setTimeout`.

E.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [isDataLoaded, setIsDataLoaded] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDataLoaded) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [isDataLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setIsDataLoaded(true), 4000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading && <div>Loading....</div>}
      {!isLoading && (
        <header className="App-header">
          <a className="App-link" href="https://reactjs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('App', () => {
  test('renders without error', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.App').exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  test('renders learn react link', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(4000);
    })
    wrapper.update();
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find('.App-link').text()).toBe('Learn React');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73051795/App.test.tsx (11.204 s)
  App
    ✓ renders without error (38 ms)
    ✓ renders learn react link (21 ms)

  console.log
    <App>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <a className="App-link" href="https://reactjs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    </App>

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/73051795/App.test.tsx:19:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.704 s
```

package version:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

Comment: Thanks @slideshop2. This works fine for me. Could you also let me know, how to test it if I have to update setIsLoading based on multiple API calls. Instead of settimeout, if there are some API calls, once all the APIs are resolved, I need to do setIsLoading.

Comment: @Suniltc If you have a new question, search it firstly, if there is no similar question and answer, then ask a new one.